# Find text with select in 2 columns mySQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am making an autocomplete form and requesting names from my database. This is the table in my database

`user_id | firstname | lastname`

I can get the data for a "searchterm" using this

```
$query = "SELECT user_id, firstname, lastname FROM users WHERE   firstname like :searchterm  ";
```

But I want to expand it so I could also search both firstname and lastname at the same time, for example, to search for "John D...". I think there is a way to join the two columns and then make a search. Can someone explain it?. I am just starting with this mysql thing.

Comment: It's confusing the way it's worded, tho. Does he have one search field or two? If he has only one, he might have to use `OR`

Comment: you mean: WHERE firstname like :searchterm  AND lastname like :searchterm:, But what about if I want to search for "John D" there is a space there, so it won't be nor in firstname neither in lastname.

Comment: Yes, either `AND` or `OR` - hard to say what the criteria is. @Machavity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you've got spaces in your search term, you'll often need to split the string into sections before you put it into your query. Use `AND` if you want to match all inputted search terms, or `OR` if you want to match any. Example:

`Search: john james smith`

```
<?php

$search = "john james smith";
$bits = explode(" ", $search);
foreach($bits as $key => $bit) {
    $bits[$key] = '(`field1` LIKE "' . $bit . '" AND `field2` LIKE "' . $bit . '")';
}
$sql = implode(' OR ', $bits);
// (`field1` LIKE "john" AND `field2` LIKE "john") OR (`field1` LIKE "james" AND `field2` LIKE "james") OR (`field1` LIKE "smith" AND `field2` LIKE "smith")

?>
```

Demo: https://eval.in/66808

Looks like you're using PDO (which is good), so you'll just need to put your binding parameters into that string instead, then concatenate it on at the end of your current SQL query into the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Thanks, I used your suggestion